# C++ program not writing data from file into array

Tags: c++, file-io

I wrote a C++ program to remove negatives from a huge list of numbers for which I only want the positives, but I'm having trouble getting the data from my file into the array.  Here's the specific part of the code I can't get to work:

```
int i = 0;
double list1[7925];//initial list of numbers
double list2[7925];//numbers without negatives or zero

std::fstream list1file;

list1file.open("3.1 b data file 2.txt", std::ios::out);
while (i < 7925)//There are 7925 numbers in the list
{
    list1file >> list1[i];//read data from file into list1 array
    i++;
}
//code to remove negatives from list and copy new list to another array
i = 0;
while (i <7925) {
    std::cout << list1[i] <<"\n";//output list of only positive numbers /*the actual program has "list2[i]" here but I changed it for the purpose of testing whether the data was being copied from the file to list1array*/
        i++;
    }
```

For whatever reason it spits a bunch of copies the number -9.25596e+61, which I don't think is even a number in the data file.  I've been Googling for hours and I can't figure out how to fix this.  Am I using the ">>" operator wrong?  If so, what do I do instead?

Comment: `std::ios::out` is for ***writing*** to the file. With this mode, the file will be recreaded from scratch (and the old contents lost).`out` as in **out**put.

Comment: OK, I removed that (also tried changing it to "in") but I still have the same problem.

Comment: To begin with it should be `in` because you read **in**put from the file. Secondly you need to check that you successfully opened the file. My guess is that the program just can't find it. You might want to learn about the concept of [*working directory*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) which is the directory all relative paths are relative from. Try using an absolute path to the file and see if it works.

Comment: Oh and if you forget the whole `in` versus `out` part, make a copy of the file first.

Comment: I also recommend you do something like `for (i = 0; i < 7925 && list1file >> list1[i]; ++i) { /* empty */ } std::cout << "Read " << i << " elements from the file\n";` With your current relative path I'll bet you get *zero*.